# how to use stored user profile timezone instead of setting timezone in django

Tags: python, django, date, datetime, timezone

Reading through the django docs, it seems it is highly encouraged to store the users timezone field in the user profile.

How do I use this value for all dates as opposed to the settings?

Do I have to do this for every date I use:

```
user_tz_str = 'America/Los_Angeles'
user_tz = pytz.timezone(user_tz_str)
users_date = user_tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 3, 1, 30))
```

or

```
user_date = some-date.replace(hour=23, minute=59, tzinfo=user_tz_str)
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45867250/5751147

Answer (score -1):

You might try an approach like [django-easytz](https://github.com/jamesmfriedman/django-easytz) in which you use a Django middleware implementation to get the timezone from the session or cookie and sets that as the timezone for that request.

I am not an expert in this area but I think this is possible. It may also be possible to query the user's timezone setting in a similar set up and set that as the timezone setting so you don't have to use a cookie/session approach.

Once it is set into the Django framework then Django should handle the dates in templates and the like automatically. I think.

Comment: For those viewing this after June 2021 django-easytz hasn't been updated in 8 years(!).